# Malloc or Calloc return unexpected values in string

Tags: c, string, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, garbage

I am trying to create a dynamic memory allocation string so which returns a  string removing all vowels. In the beginning, some of the strings work correctly but suddenly some of them returns with an extra value which makes me fail the test, and I am failing to complete the task. Here is the code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *disemvowel(const char *str)
{
  char buf[100];
  unsigned long i,j=0,nextsize=0;
  for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
  {
   if(*(str+i)=='a' || *(str+i)=='A' || *(str+i)=='e' || *(str+i)=='E' || *(str+i)=='i' || *(str+i)=='I' || *(str+i)=='o' || *(str+i)=='O' || *(str+i)=='u' || *(str+i)=='u') continue;
   else{
        buf[j]=str[i];
        j++;
        nextsize++;
   }
  }
  char *disemvoweStr=(char *) malloc((nextsize)*sizeof(char));
  strcpy(disemvoweStr,buf);
  printf("\nProblem=");
  puts(str);
  printf("\nSolution");
  puts(disemvoweStr);
  return disemvoweStr;
}
```

Some of them are working and return correct answer like:

Problem=This website is for losers LOL!

SolutionThs wbst s fr lsrs LL!

Problem=No offense but,
Your writing is among the worst I've ever read

SolutionN ffns bt,
Yr wrtng s mng th wrst 'v vr rd

Problem=What are you, a communist?

Solution=Wht r y,  cmmnst?

But then some of them return garbage values and test fails=
Problem=Yyy!

SolutionYyy!�

Problem=mVcoyIbLyAOpsOzRhwQUiWlwRHuhjUQDMBVSLelPRGrhzWagWhJzCVssmjQoFyLZVOxc

SolutionQQmTvvWfspPLzfNgNRGfcVrTMTtdtFNjKwmpdwbvNFXmUjydZCUxwmyYbsZfrwCmrbMzknqTNJdchjgMYHcPfUVNdHPRjbcgmVcybLyps���

Any idea why I am getting **���** at the end?
What is the solution and reason for this error?
Please help me

Comment: Try `char buf[100] = {0};` instead to set all of the values in `buf` to 0 and make sure the string will be properly terminated. You could also manually terminate it with a 0 after the loop if you like.

Comment: [Edit] and show the code that calls `disemvowel`. The problem might be there. Show a [mcve]

Comment: Doesn't look like you null terminated `buf`. Given the nature of your outputs with garbage at the end of each string, this should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't null terminate the buffer. Therefore `strcpy` wil just copy the contents of `buf` until a null character is encountered which is undefind behaviour.

Add this right after the `for`loop:

```
buf[j] = 0;
```

Also in `malloc((nextsize) * sizeof(char))`, `nextsize` doesn't include the null character. Actually you don't need `nextsize`at all, because it just mirrors `j`. So you should just have:

```
char* disemvoweStr = malloc(j + 1);
```

BTW, the `(char*)` cast is not needed, and `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.